# Auto populating textfield after dropdown selection

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, drop-down-menu

I have checked everything on this topic, but nothing helped me to solve my problem. I'm very new to PHP, Jquery, MySql.
What I'm trying to achive is to auto populate a text field from a database table after chosing one item from a drop down list. The name of the database 'dependencies'. There is one table in it called 'categories' and it has 3 columns: id, name, description.
In the dropdown I want to by able to chose from this list in name, and then get description automatically into the text field. I achived to have the working dropdown, but I wasn't able to move on.

Here is my code so far:

```
<?php

 try {

$objDb = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dependencies', 'admin', 'admin');
$objDb->exec('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');

$sql = "SELECT * 
        FROM `categories`
        ";
$statement = $objDb->query($sql);
$list = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

} catch(PDOException $e) {
echo 'There was a problem';
}

?> 
<head>
     <script src="/js/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

     <script type="text/javascript">

     $(document).ready(function() 
       {      
         $("#dropdownid").change(function(){
             $('#textfieldid').val($("#dropdownid").val());
         });

      });
</script>
</head>
<body>

<label>List</label>
<select name="name" required id="dropdownid">
        <option value=""></option>
            <?php foreach($list as $row) { ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
                    <?php echo $row['id']; ?> | <?php echo $row['name']; ?> | <?php echo $row['description']; ?>                        
                </option>
            <?php } ?>
</select>

<label>Text</label>
    <input name="description" type="text" id="textfieldid" value="">

</body>
</html>
```

I really appriciate any help.

Comment: The question is vague. What are you missing in your answer?

Comment: My problem is that I don't want to add the value of the currently selected item from the dropdown list ($("#dropdownid").val()), because it is the 'id' column. What I need is that when I select something from the dropdown list, based on the selection, get the data from 'description' field of the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this after the end tag of body ( < / body >

```
<script>
    $(function () {

        $('#dropdownid').on('change', function () {
            var selected_text=$( "#dropdownid option:selected" ).text();
            selected_text=selected_text.split('|');
            $('#textfieldid').val(selected_text[2]);
        });
    })
</script>
```

and remove in the head

```
<script type="text/javascript">

     $(document).ready(function() 
       {      
         $("#dropdownid").change(function(){
             $('#textfieldid').val($("#dropdownid").val());
         });

      });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. My problem is that I don't want to add the value of the currently selected item from the dropdown list, because it is the 'id' column. What I need is that when I select something from the dropdown list, based on the selection, get the data from 'description' field of the table

Comment: I tried this out but for some reason it doesn't work, the text field remains empty.
edit: I just updated from 1.6.4 to 1.12.2 version of jQuery and now it works, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Js

```
$(document).ready(function() {      
         $("#dropdownid").on('change', function(){
            var dropDownValue = $(this).val();
             $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'request.php',
                data: {
                    id_category: dropDownValue
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    var result = JSON.parse(data);
                    if (result.result) {
                        var string = '';
                        $.each(result.list, function(key, value) {
                            string += value.field_name+' ';
                        });
                        $('#textfieldid').text(string);
                    }
                }
            });
         });
      });
```

request.php

```
 <?php
$result = true;
try {
    $objDb = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dependencies', 'admin', 'admin');
    $objDb->exec('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');

    $sql = "SELECT * 
        FROM `categories`
        WHERE id = :id_category
        ";
    $statement = $objDb->query($sql);
    // SIf it's integer.
    $statement->bindParam(':id_category', $_POST['id_category'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $list = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    $result = false;
}
echo json_encode(compact('list', 'result'));
?>
```

Comment: thanks walkingRed, I think this is what I'm trying to get to. I tried your got but for line "string += value.field_name.' ';" it gives me a syntax error in dreamweaver, and when I test the text field is not being populated. What could be the issue? Thanks in advance and I already really appriciate your help!

Comment: I corrected it now and the error is gone. But unfortunately the text field remains empty.

Comment: @bman1986 did you changed in `field_name` with correct field name? And  did you check response from interface?

Comment: I changed the field_name to description (thats the name of the field in the database table), but it did not work out. I don't really know what do you mean by checking the response from interface. Titans help from above did work, but for it I need to leave all fields in the text of the dropdown menu, which is not the nicest way, so the ultimate solution would be if somehow I could make your version to work.

Comment: @bman1986 If you're using chrome press F12 to open `Developer tools`. Click Tab network then XHR small tab. Then change field in dropdown to lunch request. Next select name with your request and voila you dot request data

Comment: Ok, I got it, this is what it says there:
Fatal error: Call to a member function bindParam() on boolean in C:\wamp64\www\request.php on line 13
Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 0.0002 243440 {main}( ) ...\request.php:0

Comment: @bman1986 change `$statement = $objDb->query($sql);` to `$statement = $objDb->prepare($sql);` and try again

Comment: I change it. Textfield is still not populated, but now the response is different:
{list: [], result: true}
list
:
[]
result
:
true

Comment: @bman1986 ok, now you must set up right query to make it work. Does category table contain anything?

Comment: the correct name of the table is 'categories', it has 3 fields: 'id' it is an integer and auto increment; 'name' it is text; 'description' it is also text
I added around 10 records to the table. The value in 'description' is what would be needed to be filled automatically into the textfield. 'id' is used for the dropdown select id, and 'name' is the dropdown text.

Comment: @bman1986 check if `id_category` is passed correctly via request in developer tools

Comment: I tried to find out, but unfortunately I have no idea where it is possible to check it in dev tools
edit: I think I found it in Network/XHR/Headers/Form_Data it show id_category with the correct id value for all the times I chose something in the dropdown

Comment: Here is my [Preview](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3ERI4ZXXEIUSGFfcHBOMHp0dTA/view?usp=sharing), the id 1 is correct it shows for id_categroy, so I think it is passed correctly